# get all selected values from ListBox (client side)

Tags: javascript, vb.net, listbox

I'm trying to implement a custom validator in JavaScript for my vb.net page. This validator should check if in a multichoice listbox there aren't any selected values, showing an error pop up if so.

The thing is, I want to do it client side, but in my 'validateFunction' function I only get the last selected (or unselected, if it was selected already) item. I know how to do it in code-behind code, but I want to do it client-side.

*aspx code:*

```
 <asp:ListBox ID="lbEdit" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
 </asp:ListBox>
 <asp:CustomValidator id="cvEdit" runat="server" Display="None" ControlToValidate="lbEdit" ClientValidationFunction="validateFunction"/>
 <ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender runat="server" ID="vceEdit" TargetControlID="cvEdit" />
```

*JavaScript code:*

```
 function validateFunction(source, arguments) {
        var options = document.getElementById(source.controltovalidate).options;
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                if (options[i].selected == true) {
                    args.IsValid = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
            args.IsValid = false;
 }
```

As I said, since last (un)selected item will be the only one selected in the 'options' array, the validating function will always return true...

I thought of populating another array in another javascript function as the 'true selected array' and compare its values with the selected option each time the function fires.. but I think there should be a better way.

So... Is there a straight forward way to get ALL the selected items from a multichoice listbox in javascript?

Answer (score 5):

Your question is a bit unclear, and your function seems working, but what I will answer here is the last part of your question *So... Is there a straight forward way to get ALL the selected items from a multichoice listbox in javascript?*

Try this js function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function validateFunction() {
            var options = document.getElementById('<% = this.lbEdit.ClientID %>').options;
            var selectedItems;
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                if (options[i].selected == true) {
                    if (selectedItems) {
                        selectedItems = selectedItems + ";" + options[i].value;
                    }
                    else {
                        selectedItems = options[i].value;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (selectedItems) {
                alert(selectedItems);
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert("No item was selected");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

And this is the aspx code, I removed the validator

```
 <asp:ListBox ID="lbEdit" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" >
 </asp:ListBox>
    <asp:Button ID="test" runat="server" Text="send"  OnClientClick="return validateFunction();"/>
```

In the developer tools of your browser you can see a detailed information about all the properties of your object

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I haven't had any time because of a new and urgent project  we had incoming... still on it, damn...

To the response, in a look it seems your code does the same as mine, so `options[i].selected == true` only would fire once in my code, with the last clicked option... 

My developer tools doesn't ever set more than one 'selected=true'. Maybe I have declared the listbox the wrong way? I hope to have some time left on monday to make a further review and maybe open again the question. In the meantime I can't give you the bounty, at least an upvote for the effort, Thanks!!!

Comment: Actually I notice it would be the same awarding you or not, as I've read, so bounty for you, you earned it.

Anyways my workaround would be creating a JavaScript array, and each time the listbox.selected fires, toggle that index' state (true <---> false) ... will be back with news I guess ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
let a1 = [
{
    Selected:false,
},
{
    Selected:false
},
{
    Selected:false
}];
```

if (a1.some(i => i.Selected))
    console.log(true);
else
    console.log(false);

Maybe what you want